# Passing parameters to other activities android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a ListView with some info, when i press on LisView row i want to go to other activity and pass row argument to it.

For now i have this:

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

```
Thread my_files_thread = new Thread(){

    //start thread
    public void run (){
        try{

            startActivity(new Intent("android.app.reader.FILES"));


        }catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{

                //finish();
            }
    }

};// Brackets means that thread is closing

my_files_thread.start();
```

}

Files class:

```
public class Files extends Activity{

    public String name = null;

    @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.files);  

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        name = name;
    }
}
```

So i want to call setter and then open that activity. I am able to do this ? Or there are other way i should do.

Thanks.

Comment: why are you using thread to start new Activity? You dont need to introduce thread in this simple task

Comment: what do you mean row argument? is it the item position you clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I don't understand why you are using thread in `onListItemClick`. I don't think any use of it.

Use the following code to start a new activity from `onListItemClick`

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.app.reader.FILES");  
intent.putExtra("whatever", "value to pass");
startActivity(intent);
```

And retrieve this value in `Files` activity using following code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
    Intent fromIntent = getIntent(); //returns intent which started this activity
    String myValue = fromIntent.getStringExtra("whatever"); //returns the value passed by old activity
...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `putExtra` to add the argument to the intent.

```
Intent i= new Intent("android.app.reader.FILES");
    i.putExtra("arg", position);
    startActivity(i);
```

In the destination Activity use

```
Intent i1 = getIntent();
int pos = i1.getIntExtra("arg")
```

to get the value.